# inner call unit test with Enzyme and Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, enzyme, sinon

I am trying to write the test for the function with an inner call in enzyme and Sinon, but I encounter some issues about the inner call.

Here is my code:

*Chat.js*

```
sendMssage = text => {
    const { user } = this.props;
    let message = this.messageModel.normalize(text);

    this.socketClient.onSendMessage(message, user);
    this.addMessage(message);
  };
```

*test.js*

```
  it('should call sendMessage function', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Chat />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    sinon.spy(instance.socketClient(
    message,
    user,
  ));
    socketClicent.onSendMessage(message, user);
    Instance.sendMessage(message);
  });
```

It throws an error:

> instance.socketClient is not a function

Can anybody help me out understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try initializing the socketClient as a sinon fn first. Then call its instance(and the data), and in the end the instance of the sendMessage. Hope it works. This is on top of my head,  I can have a more detailed look a bit later if you figure this out. I am on mobile.

Comment: Is Chat.js and ChatWindow the same component? Do you mind sharing the complete component code?

Comment: @etarhan they are the same component, I have edited this post

Comment: Are you by any chance wrapping the component in a HOC?

Comment: @DimitrisEfst I have tried this way... but it seems what I did was not correct

Comment: @etarhan For this part, no HOC I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are doing the following:

```
sinon.spy(instance.socketClient(
  message,
  user,
));
```

I'm guessing socketClient is an object instance and not a function, but I can't be sure without seeing the code of this part.

If think you intend to spy on the method `onSendMessage` of `socketClient`. `sinon.spy` is expecting for you to either pass a function or an object + function (if you are trying to spy on a instance method). Try the following:

```
sinon.spy(instance.socketClient, 'onSendMessage');
```

Complete solution:

```
it('should call sendMessage function', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Chat user={user} />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  const socketClient = new socketEvent();
  const spy = sinon.spy(socketClient, 'onSendMessage');
  instance.socketClient = socketClient;
  instance.sendMessage(message);
  sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, message, user);
});
```

Comment: Hi etarhan, thanks for your solution, exactly, I want to spy the instance method, but when I change my code to this, another error occurred.... Cannot read property 'onSendMessage' of undefined, what am I doing wrong

Comment: actually, I create an instance of socketEvent class in Chat.js, named as socketClient, and onSendMessage is a function defined in socketEvent class

Comment: inside wrapper.instance(), it has the function sendMessage, and there is no property named socketClient, so wrapper.instance().socketclient is undefined, I realise this issue, and I try to change it to its original class, const spy = sinon.spy(socketEvent, 'onSendMessage'). Theoreticall, it should spy successfully, but it threw an error 'TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property onSendMessage as function
'

Comment: @HungryBird onSendMessage is not a class method, but an instance method. assuming socketEvent is your class name, you would first need to instantiate it with new socketEvent()

Comment: yes, you are right, now spy successfully after I instantiate it :) Back to my chat component, when I use chat component instance to call sendMessage, it still throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSendMessage' of undefined :(